# .NET C/C++ P/INVOKE exception

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, pinvoke

Runnnig this code getting this error, could any one help figure out what is going on here?

[image]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace LSATest
{
class Program
{


    public static List<string> listBox1 = new List<string>(); 
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DateTime systime = new DateTime(1601, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0); //win32 systemdate

        UInt64 count;
        IntPtr luidPtr = IntPtr.Zero;
        LSAClass.LsaEnumerateLogonSessions(out count, out luidPtr);  //gets an array of pointers to LUIDs

        IntPtr iter = luidPtr;      //set the pointer to the start of the array

        for (ulong i = 0; i < count; i++)   //for each pointer in the array
        {
            IntPtr sessionData;

            LSAClass.LsaGetLogonSessionData(iter, out sessionData);

            LSAClass.SECURITY_LOGON_SESSION_DATA data = (LSAClass.SECURITY_LOGON_SESSION_DATA)Marshal.PtrToStructure(sessionData, typeof(LSAClass.SECURITY_LOGON_SESSION_DATA));

            //if we have a valid logon
            if (data.PSiD != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                //get the security identifier for further use
                System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier sid = new System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier(data.PSiD);

                //extract some useful information from the session data struct
                string username = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(data.Username.buffer).Trim();      //get the account username
                string domain = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(data.LoginDomain.buffer).Trim();    //domain for this account  
                string authpackage = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(data.AuthenticationPackage.buffer).Trim();    //authentication package

                LSAClass.SECURITY_LOGON_TYPE secType = (LSAClass.SECURITY_LOGON_TYPE)data.LogonType;
                DateTime time = systime.AddTicks((long)data.LoginTime);                  //get the datetime the session was logged in

                //do something with the extracted data, ie, add to a display control....
                listBox1.Add("User: " + username + " *** Domain: " + domain + " *** Login Type: (" + data.LogonType + ") " + secType.ToString() + " *** Login Time: " + time.ToLocalTime().ToString());

            }
            iter = (IntPtr)((int)iter + Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(LSAClass.LUID)));  //move the pointer forward
            LSAClass.LsaFreeReturnBuffer(sessionData);   //free the SECURITY_LOGON_SESSION_DATA memory in the struct
        }
        LSAClass.LsaFreeReturnBuffer(luidPtr);   //free the array of LUIDs

    }
}
```

}

Comment: This is not C nor C++. This is C#.

Answer (score 1):

The error is because `sessionData` is `null`. That's because `LsaGetLogonSessionData` is failing. To diagnose this further, you need to start paying attention to the return value of the API functions and checking error codes in case of failure. That's your next step.

As an aside, you have declared the `count` variable incorrectly. In the C header file it is declared as `ULONG`. That's an unsigned 32 bit integer which makes it `uint` in C#. I've not checked anything more than this.